# rewrite index.cgi to index.py

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, flask

I have a Flask app running on Centos as CGI.
The cgi script is index.cgi.

I now want index.cgi to be index.py.

I have given out some urls to people that would be like this...

https://anysite.com/errorlog/index.cgi/search_body_request/?startdate=2016-01-01&enddate=2016-12-31&srchtxt=Persistence+error

How can I rewrite index.cgi to index.py and the urls that contain index.cgi in them will still work but be routed to index.py instead?

I want to remove index.cgi from my server and have index.py instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I solved it...

This Flask app resides in a folder named errorlog off the main htdocs folder.
Here is what I did and now it seems to work.

```
Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py .rb

RewriteEngine On
# Lets rewrite all request to https...
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Lets rewrite all request containing index.cgi to /errorlog/index.py
RewriteRule ^index.cgi?(.*)$ /errorlog/index.py$1 [L]

# Lets rewrite all request to the errorlog folder with requested file not found to /errorlog/index.py
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /errorlog/index.py/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I wish I knew why!
I commented it the way I think it works...

Someone feel free to tell me in plain English how this works!